# Memory leaks caused by printf()

Tags: c, memory-leaks, valgrind

I'm writing a program in which I have to print a value to 6 octal digit places. I did the following:

```
printf("%06o %9d %s %s -> %s\n", mode, size, calenderSize, pathname, linkname);
```

Adding the 0 before the 6 fixed my problem, however when I use [`valgrind`](http://valgrind.org/) to check for memory leaks, I'm getting a memory leak message. Before I put the 0, there were no memory leaks; everything had been freed. Can someone please explain this problem and is there another solution to forcing `printf` to print to 6 digit places?

Comment: What leaks are you getting? Are they leaked at the end of the program, or just after the call?

Comment: What are your variable types?

Comment: Using a dot `.` in place of the zero `0` will also force 6 digits of octal output; whether it will also cure the memory leak is unclear. Which platform are you on (O/S and version, compiler and version, C library and version)?  It is an unlikely problem to run into.  Can you show the relevant parts of the `valgrind` output?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please include the output from `valgrind` in an edit to the question.  It would be great to see the code from an SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)) so that people can reassure themselves that it is not an issue on their machines, if nothing else.  Also, was it the `6` that triggered the leak and the `06` that fixed it? Your question isn't quite clear on this point.

Comment: Don't be surprised if valgrind has detected something like an "allocated once then reused buffer" within the standard library. Normally valgrind comes with a list of false positives it should ignore, and often this list isn't quite as up-to-date as possible